# Commutator of gauge field and the scalar field in the Stueckelberg Lagrangian with gauge-fixing terms

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, commutator, gauge

I was trying to add a gauge fixing term to Stueckelberg Lagrangian and cancel the mixing term between scalar $\chi$ field and vector $A_\mu$ field.

$${\cal L}_{Stueckelberg} = -\frac{1}{4}V_{\mu\nu}V^{\mu\nu} + \frac{m_v^2}{2}V_\mu V^\mu\tag{1}$$

where $V_{\mu} \equiv (A_\mu - \partial_\mu \pi)$ and $V_{\mu\nu} \equiv (\partial_\mu V_\nu - \partial_\nu V_\mu)$ with sign convention $(+,-,-,-)$.

By simplifying that, we get:

$${\cal L}_{Stueckelberg} = -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} + \frac{m_v^2}{2}(A_\mu - \partial_\mu \pi)(A^\mu - \partial^\mu \pi).\tag{2}$$

Our gauge-fixing Lagrangian is:

$${\cal L}_{GF} = -\frac{1}{2\xi}(\partial_\mu A^\mu - \xi m_v \chi)^2\tag{3}$$

where $\chi \equiv m_v \pi$.

When the gauge fixing term is added up to the Stueckelberg Lagrangian:

$${\cal L}_{Stueckelberg} + {\cal L}_{GF} = -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}  + \frac{m_v^2}{2}A^\mu A_\mu - m_v A_\mu\partial^\mu\chi + \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \chi)^2 - \frac{1}{2\xi}(\partial_\mu A^\mu)^2 - \frac{1}{2}\xi m_v^2\chi^2 + m_v \partial_\mu A^\mu \chi.\tag{4}$$

$\\$

At this point the mixing terms $- m_v A_\mu\partial^\mu\chi$ and  $m_v \partial_\mu A^\mu \chi$ should cancel out, and to show that we must be able to write:

$$A_\mu \partial^\mu \chi = \partial_\mu A^\mu \chi.\tag{5}$$

And thus:

$$ \partial_\mu \left[ A^\mu ,\chi  \right] = 0.\tag{6}$$

I am confused because these fields are in fact operators and therefore might not commute.

Can you give me a brief description of when I can apply this equation, and why this happens?

Comment: Comment to the post (v3): There seems to be a sign error in eq. (3). The 2 mixing terms currently adds up rather than cancel (up to total derivative terms). Please double-check.

Comment: You are so right! Indeed eq 3. should have been ${\cal L}_{GF} = -\frac{1}{2\xi}(\partial_\mu A^\mu + \xi m_v \chi)^2\tag{3}$ which makes eq. 5 and 6 irrelevant because this way the mixing terms become $A_\mu \partial^\mu \chi + \partial_\mu A^\mu \chi = \partial_\mu (A^\mu \chi)$ and therefore does not contribute to the action since that term is now a total derivative. Thank you.